# arara: making rules for a script that takes multiple flags and arguments

Tags: arara

I'm working on an [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) rule for [`indent.plx`](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx) which can be called in a few different ways:

- `indent.plx myfile.tex` (outputs to the terminal)
- `indent.plx -w myfile.tex` (overwrites original file and outputs to terminal)
- `indent.plx -o myfile.tex outputfile.tex` (outputs to a separate file and outputs to terminal)
- `indent.plx -s myfile.tex` (silent mode, no ouptput to terminal)

I'd like to wrap up these choices (and others, hopefully) in one tidy `arara` rule. So far I have

```yaml
!config
# indent rule for arara
# author: cmhughes
# requires arara 3.0+
#
# Sample use:
# % arara: indent
# % arara: indent: {overwrite: true}
# % arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
# % arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
# % arara: indent: {overwrite: false}
#
identifier: indent
name: Indent
command: indent.plx @{overwrite} "@{file}"
arguments:
- identifier: overwrite
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( parameters.overwrite, "-w","" ) }
```

How can I extend my rule to include the other options to output to a separate file and for silent mode?

I'd like to be able to use, for example, each of the following

```
% arara: indent: {overwrite: false, outputFile: outputfile.tex}
% arara: indent: {outputFile: outputfile.tex, silent: true}
```

Comment: Got it working in windoze 7 `:-)`.

Comment: @HarishKumar superb, that's great news! I might call on you for some details before I release it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll make a humble attempt. `:)`

First, let's define which directive arguments we might use:

- `silent`: it holds a boolean value (in the `arara` context, it can be `on/off`, `yes/no`, `true/false`, and `0/1`), which expands to `-s` if present and true. This is an independent argument.
- `overwrite`: it also holds a boolean value, which expands to `-w` if present and true. This argument has an impact on the next argument (`output`), which invalidates its use when present and true, that is, overwriting the file has higher priority than generating an output to another file.
- `output`: it holds any value which will be the output generated by the script. Only if the `overwrite` is absent or resolves to false, this value will be available, if not empty.

Currently, `indent.plx` requires `-o <original file> <new file>`. I mentioned to Chris in the chatroom that would be nice to have the `<new file>` value near to its corresponding flag `-o`. Two rules, one for each situation, are presented.

Requiring, e.g, `indent.plx -o outputfile.tex myfile.tex`:

```
!config
# indent rule for arara
# author: cmhughes
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: indent
name: Indent
command: indent.plx @{silent} @{ isEmpty( overwrite, isNotEmpty( output, "-o ".concat('"').concat(output).concat('"') ), overwrite ) } "@{file}"
arguments:
- identifier: overwrite
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( parameters.overwrite, "-w" ) }
- identifier: silent
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( parameters.silent, "-s" ) }
- identifier: output
  flag: <arara> @{ parameters.output }
```

Requiring, e.g, `indent.plx -o myfile.tex outputfile.tex`:

```
!config
# indent rule for arara
# author: cmhughes
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: indent
name: Indent
command: indent.plx @{silent} @{ isEmpty( overwrite, isNotEmpty( output, "-o"  ), overwrite ) } "@{file}" @{ isEmpty( overwrite, isNotEmpty( output, '"'.concat(output).concat('"') ) ) }
arguments:
- identifier: overwrite
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( parameters.overwrite, "-w" ) }
- identifier: silent
  flag: <arara> @{ isTrue( parameters.silent, "-s" ) }
- identifier: output
  flag: <arara> @{ parameters.output }
```

Then we can use the following directives:

```
% arara: indent: { overwrite: false, output: outputfile.tex }
% arara: indent: { output: outputfile.tex, silent: true }
% arara: indent: { overwrite: true, silent: yes }
```

There we go! `:)`